# How to initialize a two dimensional string DataFrame array in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, spyder

I want to initialize a 31756x2 data frame of strings.
I want it to look like this:

```
index  column1     column2

0        A           B
1        A           B
.
.
31756    A           B
```

I wrote:

```
content_split = [["A", "B"] for x in range(31756)]
```

This is the result:

[image]

I did get a two dimensional list, but I want the columns to be separated like in a data frame, and I can't seem to get it to work (like column1: A.. , column2: B...)

Would love some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` constructor only:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "B"] for x in range(31756)], columns=['col1','col2'])
print (df.head())

  col1 col2
0    A    B
1    A    B
2    A    B
3    A    B
4    A    B
```

Or:

```
N = 31756
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A'] * N, 'col2':['B'] * N})
print (df.head())
  col1 col2
0    A    B
1    A    B
2    A    B
3    A    B
4    A    B
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(list('AB'), (31756, 1)), columns=['col1','col2'])
```

Or just passing a dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A']*31756, 'B':['B']*31756})
```

If using this latter method you may want to explicitly sort the columns since the dictionary doesn't have order:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A']*31756, 'B':['B']*31756}).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(31756))
df.loc[:,'column1'] =  'A'
df.loc[:,'column2'] = 'B'
```

Answer (score 2):

For fun

```
pd.DataFrame(index=range(31756)).assign(dict(col1='A', col2='B'))
```